# Option of Curl return

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the URL stream (.m3u8) from here:
https://chch.cdn.clearcable.net/

I tried with cURL:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://chch.cdn.clearcable.net/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$res = curl_exec($ch);    
echo $res;
```

However the URL stream is not present in the code.
Do I need some extra function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell curl to return the data instead of output it. If you use this setting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

The `$res` should contain the data you expect. I can confirm this works for me. If it's not for you, try this, after thet call to `curl_exec`:

```
if($res === false) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $res;
}
```

When running on the web, as you mentioned, you will need to view the source to see any code that is parsed by the browser. Or you can use methods like `print_r` or `var_dump` to view it on the page.

Comment: I added the setting but it does not work I don't see the .m3u8 anywhere.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: I can confirm that your code above with my suggestion works. I have added more information for you to test what's wrong.

Comment: I didn't think about using "view-source:" before my link ... this way I see the m3u8.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem :) You can mark my answer as correct by clicking the tick under the votes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if its returning any value using `print_r()` function

Try code below

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://chch.cdn.clearcable.net/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
 $post = json_decode($res ,true);

print_r($post);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `file_get_contents()` to stream the entire file into a string. But using it alone will generate an error: `SSL operation failed with code 1..`

[This link describes why.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php)

Try this code:

```
// Create a stream
$opts = [
    "ssl" => [
    "verify_peer" => false,
    "verify_peer_name" => false
  ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$res = file_get_contents("https://chch.cdn.clearcable.net/", false, $context);

echo $res;
```